# Delay for click in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I perform 3 seconds delay for each click in selenium? for example I have this code and I want to have 3 seconds delay to page loads completely. It is clicking on buttons in a pagination:

```
for( int i = 1; i<6; i++)
{
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='injectview']/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul/li["+ i +"]/a")).Click();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Thread.Sleep()` because that will only wait a hard coded value of time. What if the page isn't done loading by then? What if the page loads faster than 3s? A better practice is to use `WebDriverWait` to wait for the page to finish loading.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    By locator = By.XPath(".//*[@id='injectview']/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul/li[" + i + "]/a");
    IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(locator);
    element.Click();
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(element));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));
}
```

The logic is like this:

1. Click the pagination link.
2. Wait for the pagination link to go stale. Stale means that the element is no longer in the DOM which indicates that the new page is loading.
3. Wait for the element to be clickable which indicates the new page has (likely) completed loading.
4. Repeat 1-3 for each link.

NOTE: Your XPath is going to be fragile with that many layers of nesting. If you will provide the HTML around the navigation links, I can probably create a less fragile locator.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the whole request with `wait.until(...);` it should wait for the completion of each call.

Comment: Well you removed the `Thread.Sleep()` but I don't think your answer is specific enough to be useful. What does "wrap the whole request" mean? You have OP's code, take it and post the final answer that he should use given your recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

A cleaner solution in my opinion would be to use async

```
for( int i = 1; i<6; i++)
{

   await PutTaskDelay();
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='injectview']/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul/li["+ i +"]/a")).Click();
}

 async Task PutTaskDelay()
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }
```

Comment: This really isn't any different than `Thread.Sleep()` which is a bad practice.